# MAterial UI - Stepper connectors position problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm using the stepper provided by the MUI in my Next.js app, I'm facing a problem with the connectors, when first loading the page the connectors are positioned correctly as they are supposed to be , between the steps , for me it is between step 1 - 2 and 2 - 1, but for some reason when refreshing the page the connectors are moving upwards , on top of step 2 and step 3, why is that ? could someone please help me , I have google and tried to fix the problem but can't seem to find where the problem lies :

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Stepper from "@mui/material/Stepper";
import Step from "@mui/material/Step";
import StepLabel from "@mui/material/StepLabel";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import StepperForm from "./StepperForm";
import { StepIconProps } from "@mui/material";

const steps = ["Enter Voucher Code", "Select Shop", "Confirm"];

// Custom StepIcon component
const CustomStepIcon: React.FC<StepIconProps> = ({ completed, active, icon }) => (
<div
className={`w-6 h-6 p-5 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center ${
  active ? "bg-[#FFD111]" : completed ? "bg-[#000000]" : "bg-[#000000]"
 }`}
 >
{completed ? (
  <img src="/path/to/completed-icon.svg" alt="Completed" />
  ) : (
  <span className="text-white">{icon}</span>
  )}
  </div>
  );

   const renderStepContent = (step: number) => {
  switch (step) {
   case 0:
  return <StepperForm />;
  case 1:
  return <div>Step 2 Content: Select Shop</div>;
  case 2:
  return <div>Step 3 Content: Confirm</div>;
default:
  return null;
  }
};

const HorizontalStepper = () => {
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

const handleNext = () => {
setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
};

const handleHome = () => {
// Add the logic to navigate to the home page
console.log("Navigate to home");
};

return (
<div className="w-full flex flex-col gap-10">
  <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
    {steps.map((label, index) => (
      <Step key={label}>
        <StepLabel StepIconComponent={CustomStepIcon}>{label}</StepLabel>
      </Step>
    ))}
  </Stepper>
  <>
    {renderStepContent(activeStep)}
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", pt: 2 }}>
      <Box sx={{ flex: "1 1 auto" }} />
      {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? (
        <Button onClick={handleHome}>Home</Button>
      ) : (
        <Button onClick={handleNext}>Next</Button>
      )}
    </Box>
  </>
 </div>
 );
 };

 export default HorizontalStepper;
```